# Solving a Pi product.

Tags: products

How the value of this $P_k$ is calculated from the first equation. Thank you.

$$k \geq m$$
$$P_k=P_0\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{\alpha}{(i+1)\mu}\prod_{j=m}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha}{m\mu}$$
$$P_k=\frac{P_0\left(\frac{\alpha}{\mu}\right)^k}{m!m^{k-m}}$$

Comment: Where is the $\pi$ ?

Comment: Did you try induction?

Comment: Is $mu$ in the right product a $\mu$?

Comment: isn't there a $j$ missing in the expression of the second product?

Comment: Hi, i am working with Queueing Theory but i don't understand this step in the book as it is written straight away like this, without any details. Can you break it down ?

Comment: "Induction"? Induction on what and for what?

Comment: @AftabAhmedKhan Then what  gives $\;\pi\;$ , or where does $\;\pi\;$ fit?

Comment: @Timbuc, i don't know. I just want to know how this step is performed.

Comment: maybe Pi stands for $P_i$ and not $\pi$

Comment: Please note that we prefer questions typed out, not in picture form (you can have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to write math here).

Comment: Also, what you refer to as "pi" is actually a *product* symbol: $\prod_{i = 0}^{n} a_i$ is, by *definition* a shorthand for $a_0 \dotsm a_n$.

Comment: @Surb I believe that the OP's confusion comes from the usage of $\prod$ to denote a product. As for comment 4, from how the formula is structured I'd say that there is no missing $j$: just take the second product as $\left(\frac{\alpha}{m\mu}\right)^{k-m}$.

Comment: @A.P. But that _is_ a pi. (A capital letter pi, so I guess you should write it as Pi.)

Comment: @columbus8myhw Yes, $\prod$ *is* a capital $\pi$, but as a mathematical *symbol* it indicates the operation of taking the product of the elements of a sequence, just like $\sum$ indicates [summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) of the terms of a sequence. (By the way: the respective LaTeX macros are `\prod` and `\sum`)

Comment: @A.P. Yeah, I know, but it's still a Pi. Just not the _number_ pi. (And you could, theoretically, use `\Pi` and `\Sigma`.)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the correct expression is
$$
P_k = P_0\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{\alpha}{(i+1)\mu}\prod_{j=m}^{k-1}\frac{\alpha}{m\mu}
$$
we just have to count. The total number of factors of $\alpha/\mu$ are $k$, hence we should have $(\alpha/\mu)^k$. The total number of factors of $1/m$ are $k-m$, so we should have $1/m^{k-m}$. The product with $1/(i+1)$, when $i$ runs from $0$ to $m-1$ gives you $1/m!$. All in all, the result is
$$
P_0\frac{(\alpha/\mu)^k}{m^{k-m}m!},
$$
as stated.

Comment: @A.P. Indeed, thanks for pointing out. The answer is updated accordingly.